Computation of a categorical colimit
Consider the sequence of abelian groups
$$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot2}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot2}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot2}{\longrightarrow}\cdots$$
I would like to compute the colimit of this sequence in the category of abelian groups.
If we number the copies of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ in an ascending manner, such that the leftmost is the 1st copy, from which we have a morphism to the 2nd copy and so on, we know that for morphisms $\varphi_i:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}_{(i)}\to colim\,F$ (where $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}_{(i)}$ denotes the $i$'th copy in our sequence, in lack of knowledge of a better notation), the diagram has to be commutative. Now, we see that the composed morphism
$$\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}_{(i)}\overset{\cdot4}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}_{(i+2)}$$ is just the zero morphism, hence every $\varphi_i$ has to be the zero morphism as well (since for $x\in\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}_{(i)}$, we have that $\varphi_i(x)=\varphi_{i+2}(4x)=\varphi_{i+2}(0)=0$).
I don't know how to continue from here, but my intuition tells me that the colimit should be the trivial group. How do I show/disprove this?

"the category of isomorphic groups"?

The colimit is (usually) defined via a universal property. Have you tried checkinng whether your guess satisfies this definition?

@NaïmFavier sorry, corrected now to "abelian groups" :)

$\mathbb Z / 4 $ is $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ I suppose? You should at least put parentheses around the $4$

Show that any cocone factorises through $0$ and you win (it is easy since all the morphism are $0$)

@julio_es_sui_glace The notation $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is standard.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for the info, this is the first time I see it

You have a cocone $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z)_i \to 0$, and for every cocone on $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z)_i$ given by $\varphi_i: \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z \to C$, you get
$$\varphi_{i}(x) = \varphi_{i+2}(4x) = 0$$
Using the commutativity of the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>{2\cdot}>>\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2\cdot}>> \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2 \cdot}>> \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2 \cdot}>> \dots \\
& @VV{\varphi_i}V @VV{\varphi_{i+1}}V @VV {\varphi_{i+2}}V\\
\dots @= C @= C @= C @= \dots
\end{CD}$$
Thus $\varphi_i = \mathbb Z/ 4 \mathbb Z \to 0 \to C $ and your cocone factorises through $0$, and since $0$ is a zero object in $\mathbf{Ab}$, this is the only factorisation possible, thus $0$ is your colimit.
Here is a small diagram depicting the factorisation
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>{2\cdot}>>\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2\cdot}>> \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2 \cdot}>> \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z @>{2 \cdot}>> \dots \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\dots @= 0 @= 0 @= 0 @= \dots \\
& @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\dots @= C @= C @= C @= \dots
\end{CD}$$
We can see that the morphism $0 \to C$ is unique since $0$ is initial.

Let us abstract from this example.

Lemma. Let $A_0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to \cdots$ be a sequence of homomorphisms of abelian groups such that for every $a \in A_n$ there is some $m \geq n$ such that the image of $a$ in $A_m$ is zero. Then $\mathrm{colim}_n A_n$ is zero.

Proof: Follows immediately from the explicit construction of the colimit.
Here is a proof using the universal property: $A_{\infty} := \mathrm{colim}_n A_n$ is generated by the images of the $A_n$ (since the subgroup generated by the $A_n$ satisfies the same universal property), so it suffices to prove that each $A_n \to A_{\infty}$ is zero. Let $a \in A_n$. Choose $m \geq n$ such that $A_n \to A_m$ kills $a$. Since $A_n \to A_{\infty}$ factors over it, it also kills $a$, hence the claim. $\checkmark$

Corollary. Let $A_0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to \cdots$ be a sequence of homomorphisms of abelian groups such each composite $A_i \to A_{i+1} \to A_{i+2}$ is zero. Then $\mathrm{colim}_n A_n$ is zero.

The corollary applies here.
